# How to write to a file online using python?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a question that has had me stumped for a bit, I thought about doing this such thing:

I have an account at dropbox, and a file on that account. How would I write a string to that file, ONLINE? Like say it is on the dropbox website, and the contents of the file is the number: 1, how would I write the number: 2 to that file, without downloading it, essentially updating it? I thought about making a temporary file in the program dir, writing to that there, and then using ftp lib to re-upload the file, overwriting the original online. I would really rather not do that. Are there any streamlined methods to this?

Comment: You realise that dropbox does the file syncing automatically for you, right? Or are you thinking of doing something similar *without* dropbox?

Comment: I don't think Dropbox has an online file editing solution (I could be wrong here). I think what you're looking for is functionality that is more along the lines of what GoogleDocs offers. Also, like @GregHewgill said, Dropbox does the syncing for you. I would first check to make sure that online file I/O really is what you need to do here

Comment: I wouldn't ask the question if I didn't have online file-io as an idea ;) I understand that dropbox does file syncing automatically, but this must work on the WEBSITE(dropbox account), not the program you install on your home computer. This must work for several people on other computers. Essentially I would like to open the file ON the website, and edit it, without ever downloading or uploading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an API for Dropbox. The [Dropbox Developers](http://www.dropbox.com/developers) site seems to have lots of information about this.

> Harness the power of Dropbox to connect your app to almost any computer, smartphone or tablet, plus the web.
>
> - Easy online storage for your mobile or web app and a growing audience of more than 45 million users

Comment: I was hoping for a more native solution but I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: Beat me to it.  Dropbox uses delta encoding to manage file revisions, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(service), much like rsync.

Comment: Well, I really would not like to have to "sign up" just to get the api, so I guess I will go with the less clean way ;) Thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: You have to sign for any API so that you will not make 100000 put requests in an hour. Also Dropbox uses delta encoding as tharen mentioned, which means the software will only upload "the difference"